# Window Wrapper Class C++ (G++)

Tags: c++, class, window, wrapper, casting

I am attempting to learn about creating windows in c++, I have looked at an article about creating a wrapper class but I don't really understand it. So far I know that you can't have a class method WndProc (I dont know why) but honestly, that is all. Can somebody give an explanation, also explaining the reinterpret_cast? [Here](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1810.asp) is the article.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Window::MsgRouter(HWND hwnd, UINT message,
                                   WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
  Window *wnd = 0;

  if(message == WM_NCCREATE)
  {
    // retrieve Window instance from window creation data and associate
    wnd = reinterpret_cast<Window *>((LPCREATESTRUCT)lparam)->lpCreateParams;
    ::SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<long>(wnd));

    // save window handle
    wnd->SetHWND(hwnd);
  }
  else
    // retrieve associated Window instance
    wnd = reinterpret_cast<Window *>(::GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA));

  // call the windows message handler
  wnd->WndProc(message, wparam, lparam);
}
```

Thanks in advance, ell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MsgRouter()` procedure acts as a proxy between the Windows message handling system to the `Window` instance associated with a `HWND`. It routes Windows messages to C++ objects.

A pointer to the `Window` instance is passed to the `MsgRouter()` procedure via the last parameter of the `CreateWindow()` function. When you first create a `HWND` via `CreateWindow()` (or `CreateWindowEx()`), some messages are sent - one of them being `WM_NCCREATE`. When the procedure receives a `WM_NCCREATE` message, the `LPARAM` parameter contains a pointer to a `CREATESTRUCT` which contains the arguments that was passed into the `CreateWindow()` function. The procedure retrieves the `Window` instance pointer from the `CREATESTRUCT` and saves it in the `HWND` by setting it as an attribute of the `HWND` (`GWL_USERDATA` via `SetWindowLong()`).

Now that the pointer has been saved, the window procedure can from now on retrieve a pointer to the original `Window` instance from a `HWND` via `GetWindowLong()` when it receives a message. Finally, the window procedure calls `WndProc()` on the retrieved `Window` pointer, passing in the exact message and parameters, so the `Window` instance can handle the message.